# Can we show Airbnb booking confirmation as proof in Visa application and Immigration for Singapore?

Tags: visas, singapore, airbnb

I am travelling to Singapore with my family for a vacation and we have booked a Airbnb home. Upon contacting host, we got to know we are supposed to say we are visting them and not renting the home as the rules there dont allow short term rentals.

We are bit confused now. We see so many airbnb options and so many recent reviews. But our main concern is visa application and immigration

1. Can we show Airbnb booking confirmation as our stay proof in visa
   application?
2. Can we tell that we have booked a airbnb home/show that
   booking in immigration?

Would be really helpful if people who have stayed in airbnb at singapore can give their inputs!

Comment: On the face of it, applying for a visa with a proof of accommodation booking that violates Singaporean regulations looks like a bad idea. The ECO might conclude that if you’re willing to break that rule, you may be willing to breach immigration rules too.

Answer (score 1):

While renting out private property for preriods of less than three months is indeed illegal in Singapore, **this applies only to the landlord, not you as the guest.**  ([Source.](https://singaporelegaladvice.com/law-articles/is-airbnb-illegal-singapore))

I still wouldn't go out of my way to advertise that I'm staying at at Airbnb, but it's quite unlikely that this would even come up.  The Singapore immigration form asks for an address, but nothing else, and officers -- if they ask anything at all -- care more about how long you are staying, why you are visiting, etc.  I've staying at an Airbnb in Sg once (several years ago when it was still a grey area, not clearly banned as today), and IIRC they didn't ask anything at all.

Comment: Was this for a short term visit where you only have to fill in the form at the airport? Because OP might be asking about getting a proper visa, which is more complicated depending on where they are from.